# Load the content of the embedded file into RichEdit control on the custom license page

Tags: nsis

**Requirements / use case:**
I have a requirement to implement custom license page in NSIS. The page should look like this: [image: custom license page NSIS].

On the page I have RichEdit control which has **to display the content of a eula.rtf** file. This file is available at the compile time and **I cannot distribute it separately from the installer**, so it has to be somehow embedded into it.

Currently I am using NSIS 2.46 and MUI2. Here is how I create RichEdit control:

```
  nsDialogs::CreateControl /NOUNLOAD "RichEdit20A" ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${WS_VSCROLL}|${ES_MULTILINE}|${ES_WANTRETURN} ${WS_EX_STATICEDGE} 1.32u 56.62u 295.54u 63.38u ""
  Pop $hCtl_test_rtLicense
```

**Problem description:**
I know that the default MUI2 license page makes use of [LicenseData and/or LicenseLangString](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#alicensedata). As far as I know, in this case the .rtf file is embedded into the installer. Unfortunately **I cannot figure out how to load the content from the embedded .rtf file into my RichEdit control**, even though I looked through the License.nsh coming with NUI2 and through the NSIS source code as well.

And unfortunately **the plugins and scripts I found** ([LoadRtf plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/LoadRTF), [NsRichEdit plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsRichEdit_plug-in), [this script](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/External_License_file) and one or two more) **can only load .rtf file into the RichEdit control *at runtime***.

**Question:**
How to load the content from the embedded .rtf file into the RichEdit on the custom page?
If it is not possible, is there any other way to implement my requirement?

The only thing I could think of is wrapping my current installer into another thin NSIS installer which would silently deploy the .rtf file alongside with the current installer. This feels very messy, so I would rather not do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is at run-time. To use one of the solutions you linked to you would just extract the .rtf file and call the plugin:

```
InitPluginsDir ; Initialize $PluginsDir, it is deleted automatically when installer quits
File "/oname=$PluginsDir\lic.rtf" "MyLicense.rtf"
# Call plugin here passing in "$PluginsDir\lic.rtf" as the file to load
```

Or if you don't want to use 3rd-party plugins:

```
Page Custom MyPage
Page InstFiles

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!define SF_RTF 2
!define EM_STREAMIN 1097

Function LoadRichRtf
System::Store S
Pop $0 ; hwnd
Pop $1 ; path to rtf
FileOpen $1 $1 r
System::Get "(i, i .R0, i .R1, i .R2)iss"
Pop $2
System::Call "*(*i 0, i 0, k r2)i.r3"
System::Call "USER32::SendMessage(ir0, i${EM_STREAMIN}, i${SF_RTF}, ir3)i.s"
loop:
    Pop $0
    StrCmp $0 "callback1" 0 done
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::ReadFile(ir1, iR0, iR1, iR2, i0)'
    Push 0 # callback's return value
    System::Call "$2"
    Goto loop
done:
System::Free $2
System::Free $3
FileClose $1
System::Store L
FunctionEnd


Var hCtl_test_rtLicense
Function MyPage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

nsDialogs::CreateControl /NOUNLOAD "RichEdit20A" ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${WS_VSCROLL}|${ES_MULTILINE}|${ES_WANTRETURN} ${WS_EX_STATICEDGE} 1.32u 56.62u 295.54u 63.38u ""
Pop $hCtl_test_rtLicense
File "/oname=$PluginsDir\lic.rtf" "c:\some\local\path\License_en_US.rtf"
Push "$PluginsDir\lic.rtf"
Push $hCtl_test_rtLicense
Call LoadRichRtf

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked the fact that I can extract the file prior to showing my custom license page)